# How to make an Action show a View or a Serialized ViewModel generaly?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my whole application I use strong typed View Models. Now I have the task to show the view normaly, or provide the serialized ViewModel if a specific parameter is present.

So, the first thing comes into my mind is this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id, string apiMode)
{
    var model = new ViewModel(); //Obtain model
    if (apiMode == "json")
    {
        return Json(model);
    }
    return View(model)
}
```

Now I am wondering if there is a more generic solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is totaly possible.

We can extend the `RazorViewEngine` the following way:

```
public class AppViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private const string ApiModeParam = "API__MODE";

    public AppViewEngine()
    {
        //Performance optimization, if we do not need to lookup for vbhtml
        FileExtensions = new[] {"cshtml"};
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
    {
        var apiMode = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params[ApiModeParam];
        if (apiMode == null)
        {
            return base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache);
        }

        return GetApiResult(apiMode);
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        var apiMode = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params[ApiModeParam];
        if (apiMode == null)
        {
            return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
        }
        return GetApiResult(apiMode);
    }

    private ViewEngineResult GetApiResult(string apiMode)
    {
        switch (apiMode)
        {
            case "json":
                return new ViewEngineResult(new ApiJsonView(), this);
            case "xml":
                return new ViewEngineResult(new ApiXmlView(), this);
            default:
                return new ViewEngineResult(new[] { "API__MODE is not supported" });
        }

    }

}
```

Now we only need some Views:

```
public class ApiJsonView : IView
{
    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    {
        viewContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        //Json.NET, normaly included in MVC
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, viewContext.ViewData.Model);
    }
}

public class ApiXmlView : IView
{
    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    {
        viewContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        var model = viewContext.ViewData.Model;
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(model.GetType());
        using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(writer))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, model);
        }
    }
}
```

Last thing: We need to register it in `global.asax` in the `Application_Start` method:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AppViewEngine());
```

Now every request, appended with `?API__MODE=json` is showing the serialized ViewModel instead of an HTML Page. And the best, it is as simple as:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
    var model = new ViewModel(); //Obtain model
    return View(model)
}
```